# Sorting Javascript first sort ascending then descending

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, compare

Javascript array sort Compare function issue,
I created the below array need to sort one column as descending and keep the one column as ascending, Use simple compare function but the result not proper.
Its great extend to help me this issue,

```
var homes =[
{score: "1.40", tier: "Tier-1", regionKey: 12, regionName: "Northern America"},
{score: "1.40", tier: "Tier-1", regionKey: 21, regionName: "Northern Europe"},
{score: "1.40", tier: "Tier-1", regionKey: 0, regionName: "Rest of World (ISO)"},
{score: "1.90", tier: "Tier-2", regionKey: 0, regionName: "Rest of World (ISO)"},
{score: "2.40", tier: "Tier-2", regionKey: 12, regionName: "Northern America"},
{score: "2.20", tier: "Tier-2", regionKey: 22, regionName: "Southern Europe"},
{score: "2.30", tier: "Tier-2", regionKey: 20, regionName: "Eastern Europe"},
{score: "1.80", tier: "Tier-2", regionKey: 10, regionName: "Central America"},
{score: "2.20", tier: "Tier-2", regionKey: 20, regionName: "Eastern Europe"},
{score: "1.80", tier: "Tier-2", regionKey: 22, regionName: "Southern Europe"},
{score: "2.60", tier: "Tier-3", regionKey: 65, regionName: "Eastern Europe"},

];  
        homes.sort(scoreComparison);
     function scoreComparison(a, b) {
                var tierA = a.tier;
                var tierB = b.tier;
                var scoreA = a.score*100;
                var scoreB = b.score*100;
                var comparison = 0;
                if (tierA === tierB) {
                    if (scoreA > scoreB) {
                        comparison = -1;
                    } else if (scoreA < scoreB) {
                        comparison = 1;
                    }
                    return comparison;
                }
            }

    console.log(homes);
```

Comment: Let's try homes.sort((a, b) => {
                    return a.tier.localeCompare(b.tier) || b.score - a.score;
                })

Comment: which column is descending/ascending?

Comment: Score column is descending and tier column is ascending

Comment: Thanks Tai Le its working, please provide explanation.

Comment: @aryan, it may not work for strings like `'Tier-10'`. this is sorted before `'Tier-2'`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a chained approach by getting the difference of the column values and get the next delty if the previous value is zero.

```js
var homes = [{ score: "1.40", tier: "Tier-10", regionKey: 12, regionName: "Northern America" }, { score: "1.40", tier: "Tier-1", regionKey: 21, regionName: "Northern Europe" }, { score: "1.40", tier: "Tier-1", regionKey: 0, regionName: "Rest of World (ISO)" }, { score: "1.90", tier: "Tier-2", regionKey: 0, regionName: "Rest of World (ISO)" }, { score: "2.40", tier: "Tier-2", regionKey: 12, regionName: "Northern America" }, { score: "2.20", tier: "Tier-2", regionKey: 22, regionName: "Southern Europe" }, { score: "2.30", tier: "Tier-2", regionKey: 20, regionName: "Eastern Europe" }, { score: "1.80", tier: "Tier-2", regionKey: 10, regionName: "Central America" }, { score: "2.20", tier: "Tier-2", regionKey: 20, regionName: "Eastern Europe" }, { score: "1.80", tier: "Tier-2", regionKey: 22, regionName: "Southern Europe" }, { score: "2.60", tier: "Tier-3", regionKey: 65, regionName: "Eastern Europe" }];

homes.sort(function (a, b) {
    function getDecimal(s) { return s.match(/\d+/); };
    
    return getDecimal(a.tier) - getDecimal(b.tier) || b.score - a.score;
});

console.log(homes);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

An other possibility is to use [`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) with with `options`

> **sensitivity**
>
> Which differences in the strings should lead to non-zero result values. Possible values are:
>
> - `"base"`: Only strings that differ in base letters compare as unequal. Examples: `a ≠ b`, `a = á`, `a = A`.
> - `"accent"`: Only strings that differ in base letters or accents and other diacritic marks compare as unequal. Examples: `a ≠ b`, `a ≠ á`, `a = A`.
> - `"case"`: Only strings that differ in base letters or case compare as unequal. Examples: `a ≠ b`, `a = á`, `a ≠ A`.
> - `"variant"`: Strings that differ in base letters, accents and other diacritic marks, or case compare as unequal. Other differences may also be taken into consideration. Examples: `a ≠ b`, `a ≠ á`, `a ≠ A`.
>
> The default is "variant" for usage "sort"; it's locale dependent for usage "search".
>
> **numeric**
>
> Whether numeric collation should be used, such that "1" < "2" < "10". Possible values are `true` and `false`; the default is `false`. This option can be set through an options property or through a Unicode extension key; if both are provided, the `options` property takes precedence. Implementations are not required to support this property.

```js
var homes = [{ score: "1.40", tier: "Tier-10", regionKey: 12, regionName: "Northern America" }, { score: "1.40", tier: "Tier-1", regionKey: 21, regionName: "Northern Europe" }, { score: "1.40", tier: "Tier-1", regionKey: 0, regionName: "Rest of World (ISO)" }, { score: "1.90", tier: "Tier-2", regionKey: 0, regionName: "Rest of World (ISO)" }, { score: "2.40", tier: "Tier-2", regionKey: 12, regionName: "Northern America" }, { score: "2.20", tier: "Tier-2", regionKey: 22, regionName: "Southern Europe" }, { score: "2.30", tier: "Tier-2", regionKey: 20, regionName: "Eastern Europe" }, { score: "1.80", tier: "Tier-2", regionKey: 10, regionName: "Central America" }, { score: "2.20", tier: "Tier-2", regionKey: 20, regionName: "Eastern Europe" }, { score: "1.80", tier: "Tier-2", regionKey: 22, regionName: "Southern Europe" }, { score: "2.60", tier: "Tier-3", regionKey: 65, regionName: "Eastern Europe" }];

homes.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.tier.localeCompare(b.tier, undefined, { numeric: true, sensitivity: 'base' }) || b.score - a.score;
});

console.log(homes);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace everything below the homes declaration with;

```js
homes.sort(
  function(a, b) { 
    return a.score > b.score ? 1 : a.score < b.score ? -1 : 0;
  }
).sort(
  function(a, b){ 
    return a.tier < b.tier ? -1 : a.tier > b.tier ? 1 : 0; 
  }
);
```

flipping the < and > accordingly depending on whether you want ascending or descending order.